# Laravel Socialite Facebook images are incorrect

Tags: laravel, facebook-graph-api, laravel-socialite

I have a strange problem which I cannot figure out. I am using Laravel Socialite to allow login with Facebook account, there is a lot of users complaining that the profile image displayed on their account is incorrect, however the name etc is all fine.

It makes no sense to me as the name and the profile pic are pulled directly from FB at the same time.

```
        public function socialUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
        {
            $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())->first();

            if ($account) {
                return $account->user;
            } else {

                $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
                    'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                    'provider' => 'facebook'
                ]);

                $user = User::whereEmail( $providerUser->getId() )->first(); // changed from getEmail to getId as FB doesnt always give an email

                if (!$user) {

                    $profilePicName = md5(rand(1,10000)) . ".jpg";
                    $contents = file_get_contents( $providerUser->avatar_original );

                    Storage::disk('local')->put( 'profiles/' . $profilePicName, $contents );

                    $user = User::create([
                        'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                        'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                        'profile_path' => $profilePicName
                    ]);

                }
                $account->user()->associate($user);
                $account->save();
                return $user;
            }    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using md5, you can use the UUID generator. One of the reasons for this problem because md5 generates the same hash for the same input. for instance, when you pass md5(111) it'll generate 698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668. so if for a different user you generate the same hash key, the latest image profile will take a place and the former will replace by the latter.

Scenario:
User1:

```
$profilePicName = md5(111) . ".jpg";
$contents = file_get_contents( $providerUser->avatar_original );
Storage::disk('local')->put( 'profiles/' . $profilePicName, $contents );
$user = User::create([
            'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
            'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
            'profile_path' => $profilePicName
                    ]);
```

Scenario:
User2:

```
$profilePicName = md5(111) . ".jpg";
$contents = file_get_contents( $providerUser->avatar_original );
Storage::disk('local')->put( 'profiles/' . $profilePicName, $contents );
$user = User::create([
            'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
            'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
            'profile_path' => $profilePicName
                    ]);
```

Now they both have 698d51a19d8a121ce581499d7b701668.jpg saved in their profile. And in this case the first user profile will be the same as the second user image profile.

Comment: Yes but it’s set to generate a random number each time surely this random number cannot come up so frequently

Comment: You will never know, this random number is between 1 to 10000 1- so you’ll have limitation for only 10000 people 2- if you write a test for this code it’ll definitly will generate the same hash code at some point, it could be at the 10’th iteration or at 100’th iteration. So what i would say it’s not trustable to have a unique hash code with this formula.

Comment: Fair point buddy, I guess I was just suprised at the frequency that the hash would be generated it was quite often.